# Grunt task: Dynamic source folders & dynamic ouput folders dependant on source location

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, babeljs, grunt-contrib-watch

My project has "Scripts" folder which has a lot of sub-folder full of javascript files.

At the moment I am integrating babel as a grunt task. All files which needs to be transpiled has names "*.babel.js", so in my watch object I have such task:

> ```
> babel: {
>     files: 'Content/styles/**/*.babel.js',
>     tasks: [
>         'babel'
>     ]
> },
> ```

My babel task options object is:

> "babel": {
>       options: {
>         sourceMap: true
>       },
>       dist: {
>         files: {
>           **"dist/app.js": "src/app.js"**
>         }
>       }   }

Please pay attention to bold part. Is it possible to select all files with name "*.babel.js" and put the compiled files with the same folder as source ones?

What I'm trying to do here is avoiding to define each of the *.babel.js to the config object as there are plenty of files and there will be plenty more... + all my files are in different levels of the Scripts sub folders.

Is this possible?

Comment: Building the files object dynamically should help in your case, refer to http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, babel object:

```
{
    options: {
        sourceMap: true
    },
    dist: {
        files: [
            {
                "expand": true,
                "cwd": "Scripts/",
                "src": ["**/*.babel.js"],
                "dest": "Scripts/",
                "ext": ".js"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This compiles script file to the same folder where source file exists.